# How can I get back the URL of the current google forms response in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I'm working on a discord webhook in google scripts that returns the questions and the answers for those questions of the form when someone submits it. I would like to get the hyperlink of that current or that time the latest response but as I read a tons of documentations I couldn't find any function that returns this link.

This is the code that works, but without that thing I mentioned above:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
    var answerarray = [];
    var questionarray = [];
 

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        try {
            var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
        } catch (e) {
            var parts = answer;
        }

        if (answer == "") {
            continue;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
            answerarray.push(parts[j]);
            questionarray.push(question);

        }
    }
```

Could you help me out?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't clear: *I would like to get the hyperlink of that current or that time the latest response but as I read a tons of documentations I couldn't find any function that returns this link.* Be more specific or include an example. Also what isn't working, or give an example of what you are expecting but is not happening.

Comment: What do you mean by this url of the most recent response? Can you show some screenshots on what are you trying to obtain?

Comment: Yeah, so basically every response has a link. Its usually the https://docs.google.com/forms/d/ then the form id then edit#response= and then the response Id. I do have the form id but I dont know how to get the response's id or link because get .getId() doesnt return the one I need and either does getEditResponseUrl().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated Based On Comments

If you're trying to get a URL to the link for [a screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OyMI.png) based on an individual response ID, that is not possible currently. [Here is a list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) of all the properties and methods for responses.

However, there really shouldn't be a need to visit that page. You can access all of the information from that screen using google app scripts. If you really wanted a link to a user's response, you could generate a google sheet or document upon submission and then fill it in with whatever format you wanted (or make it mimic the pre-built one).

## Original Answer

Since you tagged google sheets as part of your question, I will take a guess that you are looking for the URL of the Spreadsheet or perhaps the time of submission?

### Spreadsheet URL

If your form is connected to a spreadsheet, then you can get the URL of your `form` variable by using the following code:

```
  //You could combine for one line, but broken out to illustrate
  var theId = aForm.getDestinationId();
  var theSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(theId);
  var theURL = theSpreadsheet.getFormUrl();
```

### Time Of Latest Response

This can be acquired without the spreadsheet. If you use your same variable `answer` you should be good with:

```
 var theTime = answer.getTimestamp();
```

Comment: the link helped me to find getEditResponseUrl(), which was what I was searching for